# Error while Executing Scala constructs with Spark 1.5.2 and Scala 2.11.7

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a simple scala object file with the following content:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext  
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._ 
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf  


object X { 
      def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val params = Map[String, String](
            "abc" -> "22",)
      println("Creating Spark Configuration");
      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("X")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val txtFileLines = sc.textFile("/tmp/x.txt", 2).cache()
      val count = txtFileLines.count()
      println("Count" + count)
    }
}
```

My build.sbt looks like:

```
name := "x"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2" % "provided"
```

I then do sbt package to create `x.jar` under `target/scala-2.11/`

When I execute the above code as:
`spark-submit --class X --master local[2] x.jar`
I get the following error:

```
Creating Spark Configuration
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at Sweeper$.main(Sweeper.scala:14)
    at Sweeper.main(Sweeper.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: Is your spark a 2.10 or 2.11 spark?

Comment: Question is what version of Scala has been used to build it. Scala binaries are not compatible between major versions (i.e. 2.10 and 2.11) and default Scala version for Spark is 2.10.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Scala 2.11 in your project. You should use spark core library build for Scala 2.11. 
Can download spark-core_2.11 from here http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=Spark

Refer spark-core_2.11 jar in project.